# How to drive a plain LCD panel (get it to work with DVI)

Tags: display, diy

I have an old iMac G5 laying around I want to transform it into a second monitor, but without any extra software on the device, but by just controlling the screen panel.

I dissasembeld the iMac and found out that the screen panel is a LM171W02-A4 (M1)
http://www.beyondinfinite.com/lcd/Library/LG-Philips/LM171W02-A4.pdf

The datasheet tells me what every pin does, but I don't know how to deal with this information. Can I buy a board online that connects to the panel and has HDMI/DVI input, or can I build a cable myself to attach DVI to the panel?

Answer (score 1):

You can buy the board which can drive almost any LCD (with appropriate eprom).
Most of them even drive backlight for you and have VGA/DVI and other ports.

Just connect the power, LVD cable, backlight, put it in a nice enclosure and you are done.

Search for "dvi vga lcd board" on eBay or something similar.
You may need to confirm the LCD panel model with the seller so you'll get the correct cables and the eprom will be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it does look like all the signals are there (data p/n 0, 1, and 2, clock p/n, and DDC clock and data).  However, you're either going to have to find someone who makes an adapter board or make one yourself.  Be aware that the differential signal connections wil have to be controlled impedance, and you will need to somehow supply 3.3v to power the panel.  Oh, you're also going to need to supply the backlight inverters and power for those as they are not built in to the display panel.

Comment: Hello, do you know where i can find a controller board ? Are all displays controllable with every controller board ? Can i use a controller board from a different panel ? Are there any tutorials on how to build a adapter board ?